# HTTPComponents and downloading the HTML images too

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I use HTTPComponents to download HTML contents in a my Java lib, but now I need to download the images included with the IMG tag. Do I have to parse the HTML and download every occurrences of the IMG tags or there is a shorter way in HTTPComponents?

Otherwise can you advise HTTP Components alternatives that do this work!